# What Drupal development environments are available besides XAMPP?

Tags: 7

I am using XAMPP for almost 2 years. Recently i found some articles that suggests that XAMPP is loading some extra libraries/dlls which is not required for a Drupal development environment. 
Is there any other options that i can adopt for Drupal development besides XAMPP?

I found [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main).

Comment: The question is interesting, but I disagree with how it's formulated. "Development environment" doesn't really have a proper definition, and what components are part of it varies greatly from person to person. You are also comparing a "full stack" of (OS), Apache, Mysql and PHP with a different webserver, nginx. Which loaded libraries that are un-neccessary will depend on what you are developing.

Comment: "XAMPP is loading some extra libraries/dlls which is not required for a Drupal development environment" - most of them can be easily disabled by commenting out the appropriate lines in some config files, if someone has some experience with Apache configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's best if your local development environment matches the environment of the servers your site(s) are actually hosted on as much as possible.  I've used XAMPP with Drupal and I haven't ever had problems relating to extra libraries being loaded.

That said, if you're looking for a Drupal-optimized solution, Acquia, the company run by the founder of Drupal, provides a [Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/downloads) which allows you to set up and host Drupal quickly on Windows or OS X.  This works similarly to XAMPP but it's easier to set up.  (Warning: Acquia's Drupal distribution is slightly different than the standard Drupal from drupal.org.  However, you can easily replace the Acquia Drupal distribution with the one from drupal.org if you want.)

For a different approach, you can try [Drupal Quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart), which is a Virtualbox VM that includes an install of Ubuntu Linux pre-configured with (as per the project page):

> - Support for Drupal 7 and Drupal 6
> - Ubuntu Linux, Apache, MySQL, APC, XDebug, IMAP, UploadProgress
> - Firefox (with developer plugins) and Chrome
> - Drush, drush make, and custom drush commands
> - Install scripts for: Apache Solr, Aegir, Hudson, and Oracle
> - Netbeans and Eclipse, configured with XDebug
> - XHProf and Webgrind profilers. Emails logged as files
> - cvs, subversion, git, bazaar

This is the "whole development environment in a box" solution.

Comment: A very nice fully loaded answer. Lets wait some minutes for others.